# Canvasjs column chart updating through json not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, canvasjs

I've been trying to figure out what's seems to the problem with this code but I can't seem to find the solution yet. So I want this column chart to refresh every second with the data from chartOne.php, the chart does update but the data doesn't show up.

Here is the chartOne.php code:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

$grabOne = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_cndts WHERE id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($grabOne)){
    $oneCount = $rows['count'];
}
$grabTwo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_cndts WHERE id='2'") or die(mysql_error());
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($grabTwo)){
    $twoCount = $rows['count'];
}
$grabThree = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_cndts WHERE id='3'") or die(mysql_error());
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($grabThree)){
    $threeCount = $rows['count'];
}

echo json_encode( array(
  array("id"=>"0","count"=>$oneCount),
  array("id"=>"1","count"=>$twoCount),
  array("id"=>"2","count"=>$threeCount)
));
```

Here is the script:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var dps = [
        {label: "Person One", y: 0} ,
        {label: "Person Two", y: 0},
        {label: "Person Three", y: 0},
    ];

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        theme: "theme2",
        title:{ 
            text: "Students' Votes"
                },
            axisY: {                
            title: ""
                },                  
            legend:{
            verticalAlign: "top",
            horizontalAlign: "centre",
            fontSize: 18

        },
        data : [{
            type: "column",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendMarkerType: "none",               
            legendText: " ",
            indexLabel: "{y}",
            dataPoints: dps
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
    var updateInterval = 1000;
    var updateChart = function () {
        $.get("chartOne.php", function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(n, val) {
                chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[n].y = val.count;
            });
        }, "json");
        chart.render();
    };
    setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);
}
```

Data on the MySQL side is like this:

```
id | count
1  | 100
2  | 200
3  | 150
```

After a second from the page load the chart turns into
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZcqL.png)

I've tried document.write(); it and the data shows well. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so thanks to @oneskinnydj's post (console.log idea). I found out that the MySQL query returned a string instead of an integer which what CanvasJS needs. So to do that you need to change the mysqli_fetch_array(); into:

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc();
```

So the end result of the php part is this:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

$grabOne = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_cndts WHERE id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grabOne)){
    $oneCount = intval($rows['count']);
}
$grabTwo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_cndts WHERE id='2'") or die(mysql_error());
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grabTwo)){
    $twoCount = intval($rows['count']);
}
$grabThree = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_cndts WHERE id='3'") or die(mysql_error());
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grabThree)){
    $threeCount = intval($rows['count']);
}

$data = json_encode( array(
                    array("id"=>"Person One","count"=>$oneCount),
                    array("id"=>"Person Two","count"=>$twoCount),
                    array("id"=>"Person Three","count"=>$threeCount)
                ));

echo $data;
```

The javascript part is the same as before but better (thanks to @oneskinnydj) change the chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[n].y = val.count; into this:

```
chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[n] = { label: val.id,  y: val.count  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are adding you data to the chart. The important line is this:

```
chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[n] = { label: val.id,  y: val.count  };
```

Full working example below, not I'm printing the json data rather than fetching it remotely, but it should work just fine if you swap back in the $.get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        <?php

        $data = json_encode( array(
            array("id"=>"Person One","count"=>20),
            array("id"=>"Person Two","count"=>10),
            array("id"=>"Person Three","count"=>15)
        ));

        echo "var data = {$data}";

?>

        window.onload = function () {
            var dps = [
                {label: "Person One", y: 0} ,
                {label: "Person Two", y: 0},
                {label: "Person Three", y: 0},
            ];

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
                theme: "theme2",
                title:{
                    text: "Students' Votes"
                },
                axisY: {
                    title: ""
                },
                legend:{
                    verticalAlign: "top",
                    horizontalAlign: "centre",
                    fontSize: 18

                },
                data : [{
                    type: "column",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    legendMarkerType: "none",
                    legendText: " ",
                    indexLabel: "{y}",
                    dataPoints: dps
                }]
            });
            chart.render();
            var updateInterval = 1000;
            var updateChart = function () {

                    $.each(data, function(n, val) {
                        console.log(n);
                        console.log(val);
                        chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[n] = { label: val.id,  y: val.count  };

                    });

                chart.render();
            };
            setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem still persist. I believe the problem is within the php query. Since I need it to query, I changed the count to a variable. Now when the variable is the result is an integer the data shows, but if I change the variable into the result of the query, the data won't show (same as before).

Comment: The console log shows that the variable from the query is a string instead of an integer.

Comment: Glad to hear it, can you upvote my answer since it was of some use to you?